# Trying to routing using params but in nested routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a navbar menu option when clicking Wires and Cables then routes to another page this page has a list of a product when clicking on product detail and then moving to another page product detail but here when clicking on product details then only URL changes the routing is not working.

Code:

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar/Navbar";
import WiresCables from "./components/pages/WiresCables"
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import ProductDetail from "./components/pages/ProductDetail";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      
      {/* <WiresCables /> */}
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Navbar />} />
        <Route exact path="/WiresCables" element={<WiresCables />}> 
          <Route exact path=":id" element={<ProductDetail />} />
        </Route>

        <Route exact path="/ProductDetail/:id" element={<ProductDetail />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Navbar.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Logo from "../../assests/Logo.png";
import Button from "../Button";
import NavLinks from "./NavLinks";
const Navbar = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <nav className="bg-white">
      <div className="flex items-center font-medium justify-around">
        <div className="z-50 p-5 md:w-auto w-full flex justify-between">
          <img src={Logo} alt="logo" className="md:cursor-pointer h-9" />
          <div className="text-3xl md:hidden" onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
            <ion-icon name={`${open ? "close" : "menu"}`}></ion-icon>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ul className="md:flex hidden uppercase items-center gap-8 font-[Poppins]">
          <li>
            <Link to="/" className="py-7 px-3 inline-block">
              Home
            </Link>
          </li>
          <NavLinks />
        </ul>
        <div className="md:block hidden">
          <Button />
        </div>
        {/* Mobile nav */}
        <ul
          className={`
        md:hidden bg-white fixed w-full top-0 overflow-y-auto bottom-0 py-24 pl-4
        duration-500 ${open ? "left-0" : "left-[-100%]"}
        `}
        >
          <li>
            <Link to="/" className="py-7 px-3 inline-block">
              Home
            </Link>
          </li>
          <NavLinks />
          <div className="py-5">
            <Button />
          </div>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

NavLinks.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { links } from "./Mylinks";

const NavLinks = () => {
  const [heading, setHeading] = useState("");
  const [subHeading, setSubHeading] = useState("");
  return (
    <>
      {links.map((link) => (
        <div>
          <div className="px-3 text-left md:cursor-pointer group">
            <h1
              className="py-7 flex justify-between items-center md:pr-0 pr-5 group"
              onClick={() => {
                heading !== link.name ? setHeading(link.name) : setHeading("");
                setSubHeading("");
              }}
            >
              {link.name}
              <span className="text-xl md:hidden inline">
                <ion-icon
                  name={`${
                    heading === link.name ? "chevron-up" : "chevron-down"
                  }`}
                ></ion-icon>
              </span>
              <span className="text-xl md:mt-1 md:ml-2  md:block hidden group-hover:rotate-180 group-hover:-mt-2">
                <ion-icon name="chevron-down"></ion-icon>
              </span>
            </h1>
            {link.submenu && (
              <div>
                <div className="absolute top-20 hidden group-hover:md:block hover:md:block">
                  <div className="py-3">
                    <div
                      className="w-4 h-4 left-3 absolute 
                    mt-1 bg-white rotate-45"
                    ></div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="bg-white p-5 grid grid-cols-3 gap-10">
                    {link.sublinks.map((mysublinks) => (
                      <div>
                        <h1 className="text-lg font-semibold">
                          {mysublinks.Head}
                        </h1>
                        {mysublinks.sublink.map((slink) => (
                          <li className="text-sm text-gray-600 my-2.5">
                            <Link
                              to={slink.link}
                              className="hover:text-primary"
                            >
                              {slink.name}
                            </Link>
                          </li>
                        ))}
                      </div>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
          {/* Mobile menus */}
          <div
            className={`
            ${heading === link.name ? "md:hidden" : "hidden"}
          `}
          >
            {/* sublinks */}
            {link.sublinks.map((slinks) => (
              <div>
                <div>
                  <h1
                    onClick={() =>
                      subHeading !== slinks.Head
                        ? setSubHeading(slinks.Head)
                        : setSubHeading("")
                    }
                    className="py-4 pl-7 font-semibold md:pr-0 pr-5 flex justify-between items-center md:pr-0 pr-5"
                  >
                    {slinks.Head}

                    <span className="text-xl md:mt-1 md:ml-2 inline">
                      <ion-icon
                        name={`${
                          subHeading === slinks.Head
                            ? "chevron-up"
                            : "chevron-down"
                        }`}
                      ></ion-icon>
                    </span>
                  </h1>
                  <div
                    className={`${
                      subHeading === slinks.Head ? "md:hidden" : "hidden"
                    }`}
                  >
                    {slinks.sublink.map((slink) => (
                      <li className="py-3 pl-14">
                        <Link to={slink.link}>{slink.name}</Link>
                      </li>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default NavLinks;
```

ProductDetail.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import data from '../../data/finolex'

const ProductDetail = () => {
    const proid = useParams();
    console.log(proid);
    const proDetail = data.filter(x=>x.id == proid.id)
    console.log(proDetail);
    const product = proDetail[0];
    console.log(product); 
  return (
    <div>
        <p>{product.productdesc}</p>
        <h4>{product.company}</h4>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ProductDetail
```

WiresCables.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Finolex from '../../data/finolex'; // Make sure this import is correct
import { NavLink, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const WiresCables = () => {
    // Initialize finolex state variable with the imported data
    const [finolexData, setFinolexData] = useState(Finolex);
    console.log(Finolex);

    return (
        <div className='grid grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-6 pt-4'>
            {/* Display */}
            {Finolex.map((item, index) => (
                <div
                    key={index}
                    className='border shadow-lg rounded-lg hover:scale-105 duration-300'>
                    <img src={item.productImage} alt={item.company} className='w-full h-[200px] object-cover rounded-t-lg' />
                    <p>{item.productdesc}</p>
                    <nav>
                    <NavLink to={`/WiresCables/${item.id}`} activeClassName="active">Product Detail {item.id}</NavLink>
                    </nav>
                    

                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default WiresCables;
```

Here CodeSandBox link:https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-bush-fdz7px?file=/src/App.js

I trying to parent child routing using params but I am not able to do.

When click on product detail then route another page and give detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend for the `ProductDetail` route to be rendered at the same time as the parent `WiresCables` route then `WiresCables` ***necessarily*** should render an `Outlet` for the nest route to render its content into.

Example:

```
import Finolex from "../data/finolex"; // Make sure this import is correct
import { NavLink, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const WiresCables = () => {
  // Initialize finolex state variable with the imported data
  const [finolexData, setFinolexData] = useState(Finolex);
  console.log(Finolex);

  return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-6 pt-4">
      {/* Display */}
      {Finolex.map((item, index) => (
        <div
          key={index}
          className="border shadow-lg rounded-lg hover:scale-105 duration-300"
        >
          <img
            src={item.productImage}
            alt={item.company}
            className="w-full h-[200px] object-cover rounded-t-lg"
          />
          <p>{item.productdesc}</p>
          <nav>
            <NavLink to={`/WiresCables/${item.id}`} activeClassName="active">
              Product Detail {item.id}
            </NavLink>
          </nav>
        </div>
      ))}
      <Outlet /> // <-- nested route content renders here
    </div>
  );
};

export default WiresCables;
```

If the above wasn't the intent, then the `"/WiresCables/:id"` `ProductDetail` route should be unnested from the parent route.

Examples:

```
<Router>
  {/* <WiresCables /> */}
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Navbar />} />
    <Route path="/WiresCables" element={<WiresCables />} />
    <Route path="/WiresCables/:id" element={<ProductDetail />} />
    <Route path="/ProductDetail/:id" element={<ProductDetail />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

or

```
<Router>
  {/* <WiresCables /> */}
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Navbar />} />
    <Route path="/WiresCables">
      <Route index element={<WiresCables />} />
      <Route path=":id" element={<ProductDetail />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/ProductDetail/:id" element={<ProductDetail />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```